# NewRelic incrementCounter not working

Tags: newrelic

I am using the newrelic-api 3.1.0 with Java SE 6+ 3.1.1 agent and I:

- Added `NewRelic.incrementCounter("Custom/MyCategory/MyLabel")` and verified that it is called multiple times.
- Created a Dashboard for "Custom/MyCategory/MyLabel"

I can see the metric in NewRelic Dashboard and can create a table or a chart with it, but its value is ever zero also if I verified that NewRelic.incrementCounter is called multiple times.

Should I configure something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was in the way I created the table/chart in custom dashboard.

Indeed in the **Value** field I selected *"Total Value"* instead of *"Call Count"*.

After I changed it to *"Call Count"* then right values have been shown.

I think that *"Call Count"* is for `NewRelic.incrementCounter` and  *"Total Value"* is for `NewRelic.recordMetric`.

Maybe someone from NewRelic can confirm this.

Comment: Yup, 'call count' is the number of times a metric has been reported, so an 'incrementCounter' only affects the call count.